# Some gcc background operation clogs my CPU

Tags: 22.04, gcc

My system is a ThinkPad T14 Gen 1 with an AMD Ryzen 7 pro 4700u, running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Gnome is Version 42.9 on Wayland.

Please see the following screenshot from Gnome System Monitor:

[image]

Some process periodically uses lots of CPU. If some other programs are active, this easily reaches 100 % on all CPU which clogs my system. At the same time there are spikes in network activity that look like a download.

Although you can see open programs in this screenshot, the same happens when the system was just rebooted and no other software is open. So I assume that this is an issue with Ubuntu.

With the help of htop I found the culprit:

[image]

Some gcc process seems to be running in background. Unfortunately I could not figure out what is being compiled here and why it is running. I did not start any gcc process myself, as mentioned, this starts right after reboot.

Can anyone already tell what this is? If not: how should I proceed to find out what's going on?

Comment: see PIDs 13025 and 13228., both running `make`. You seem to be compiling.

Comment: Yes. Something is compiling. But I am not. I did not start anything, this is being started by the system and I would like to figure out what is being compiled and how it was started. As mentioned, this starts to run right after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right PID's. This seems to be related to a faulty displaylink-driver. This might explain why my whole experience with multiple monitors did feel very sluggish ...

Comment: Continuing back, see PIDs 12863 and 12880.

Comment: It looks also like you have DKMS running, which compiles drivers.  This is typical when there's a DKMS driver installed and being compiled when you update your kernel.  It looks like the load though is *not* that heavy to "clog your CPU" that heavily.

Comment: @ThomasWard: I found several threads about dkms failing to compile on some Linux kernels. Might be one of those occasions. As I wrote: if I'm doing some work and other load is on the CPU, it very much clogs my CPU. I do not turn this computer on just to have it idling for hours.

Comment: Also: having all 16 Threads > 95 % does not leave much room for keeping the system responsive. The system monitor is just does not have enough resolution to capture the moments where the system stutters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the `displaylink-driver` package installed which might have tried an update but is also known to fail to compile on some kernels.

Right from the start this piece of software did not spark any joy and it never performed well with the docking hardware I was using it for.

So my solution here was to uninstall `displaylink-driver`:

```sh
$ sudo /opt/displaylink/displaylink-installer.sh uninstall
```

This will also uninstall two additional packages, one of which caused the above load on my CPU.

Comment: On a side note: I am really baffled what developers might be thinking when they release software that is intended to run quietly in the background but then runs amok like this. It's nice to get updates in the background, but I don't care if I get it today or tomorrow. So why not use idle time to compile instead of clogging up my system while I'm trying to do work?